# How to detect data type combined with nullable property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nullable

I am using reflection to retrieve generic class object property, by detecting their data type (e.g System.String, System.DateTime, etc) and convert value based on the data type, e.g:

```
switch (prop.PropertyType.FullName)
{
    case "System.String":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            string.Empty : Convert.ToString(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.Int32":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            -1 : Convert.ToInt32(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.DateTime":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.Double":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            0 : Convert.ToDouble(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.Boolean":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            false : Convert.ToBoolean(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    default:
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            string.Empty : Convert.ToString(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
}
```

However, when I met the property defined as *int?, double? or DateTime?* which would be a Nullable type, I cannot figure out which exact data type for the property, t**he reflection only gives me the type as "System.Nullable"**, is there anyway to detect the combined data type behind?

Comment: [Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype)

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [**@madreflection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362538/c-sharp-how-to-detect-data-type-combined-with-nullable-property/59362720#comment104918935_59362538) mentioned on comment section. You need to use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype?view=netframework-4.8) as following:

```
var propType = prop.PropertyType;

if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType) != null)
{
    // It's nullable
    propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType);
}

switch (propType.FullName)
{
    case "System.String":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            string.Empty : Convert.ToString(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.Int32":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            -1 : Convert.ToInt32(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.DateTime":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.Double":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            0 : Convert.ToDouble(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    case "System.Boolean":
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            false : Convert.ToBoolean(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
    default:
        prop.SetValue(resultObject, _propertyDataValue == DBNull.Value ?
            string.Empty : Convert.ToString(_propertyDataValue));
        break;
}
```